# JavaScript React, I can't read text file and assign a name

Tags: reactjs, text-files

I need to compare 2 company names, one is from a text file, the other from databases. I import a licence in txt file and if the names are different, a notification on page will pop up asking if I want to rename it (new name will be saved in database).

In JavaScript React, I have to write code that can read a text file, specifically one line from it. This line contains the name of the company that I need to compare with the second name which is in the database.

```js
const handleDispalyDialogButtonClick = () => {
  if (nametxt! == namedatabase) {
    setDisplayDialog(true)
  }
  handleImportButtonClick();
};
```

`nametxt` is to be the name of the company in the text file. This name needs to be imported somehow and assigned to `nametxt`.

```
[license]
lic_base=xxxx
lic_nip=xxxx
PC_Nazwa1=name of the company1
PC_Nazwa2=name of the company2
PC_Nazwa3=name of the company3
```

For example it's like `Car=BMW`.

Does anyone have a solution how to make a code which gonna import information, and assign it?

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the file you want in your `public` folder and just fetch it:

```
fetch('/path/to/the/file').then((response) => response.text())
    .then((data) => {
    // read file lines here
    const fileLines = data.split('\n')
    // find the value you are looking for and compare it to the value you get from the database
}
```

Also, the screenshot you shared looks like a TOML file, you might want to parse that with [TOML Parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/toml) to make things easier.

For the value on the database, you cannot directly interact with a database from your code. You need to have an extra layer like an API and request the data from there.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, unfortunately it doesn't work properly. When I check the console, I dont have any text that is inside of txt file.

Comment: Can't really help without more information. You might want to check the network tab in developer tools to see if the file is being downloaded.